# Mesophere cluster with nodes of different operating systems

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I want to setup a Mesophere cluster (mesos, dc/os, marathon) for running different jobs. The nodes which these jobs run on depend on the nature of the job. For e.g a job with C# code will run on a windows node. A job with pure C++ will run on Ubuntu or freebsd and so on. Each of these can again be a cluster. ie I want to have, lets say, 2 windows nodes and 4 ubuntu nodes. So I would like to know:

1. Can this be achieved in a single deployment ? Or do i need to setup different clusters for reach environment i want , one for windows, one for Ubuntu etc.
2. Regradless of a single hybrid or multiple environments, does mesos provide granularity of what the nodes send back. i.e I dont want to see high level status like job failed or running etc. My jobs write stats to a file on the system and i want to relay this back to the "main UI" or the layer that is managing all this

Comment: Afaik DC/OS neither supports Ubuntu nor Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can this be achieved in a single deployment?

If you want to use DCOS, currently offical just support centos/redhat, for ubuntu, you need to use at least 1604, which use systemd not old upstart of ubuntu. But afaik, windows is not support in DCOS.

So for your scenario, you had to use mesos directly not to use dcos, then with one cluster, you can set different mesos agent on ubuntu or windows. And you may add role or attribute when agent register to mesos master, so the framework can distinguish when dispatch job to proper agent.

BTW, for windows, you had to use at least 1.3.0 mesos which support windows, and you had to build it on windows using microsoft visual studio by yourself.

> 2. Does mesos provide granularity of what the nodes send back?

Yes, but you can not use default command executor, you need to write your own executor.

In your executor, you can set the value which you want to send back:

```
update = mesos_pb2.TaskStatus()
update.task_id.value = task.task_id.value
update.state = mesos_pb2.TASK_RUNNING
update.data = 'data with a \0 byte'
driver.sendStatusUpdate(update)
```

In your framework, you can receive it as follows:

```
def statusUpdate(self, driver, update):
    slave_id, executor_id = self.taskData[update.task_id.value]
```

[Here](https://github.com/weiyuanke/mesos-test-framework-python/tree/master/scheduler_executor) is an example I found from github which may help you about how to send your own data back.